# define value in static library in c

Tags: c, static-libraries

I have a static library (`array.a`) in c that contains a code like this :

```c
int array[ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

and `ARRAY_LENGTH` is defined in `CFG.c` like this :

```c
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10
```

my question is that if I change `CFG.c` and set `ARRAY_LENGTH` to `20`, then I have `array[20]` in my app or it remain `array[10]` ? How can I change it?

Comment: You have to recompile to get the new length.

Comment: Changing a `.c` file has no effect until you compile it. You'll also need to re-link all the programs that use the library.

Comment: thank you @Barmar but I just have array.h and array.a  both from third-party. I don't have any access to source files. is there exist another solution?

Comment: If you don't have the source code, you can't change the size of the array.

Comment: The macro is not used for changing the array size, it's just for informing the users of the library what the size is.

Comment: How is `array.a` related to `CFG.c`? Is it the file where the array is defined inside the lib?

Comment: @Gerhardh  No, CFG.c is independent file

Comment: If `CFG.c` is not the file where `array[]` is defined, the macro does not affect your library even if you rebuild the lib.

Comment: yes @Gerhardh you right. I have to ask my third-party to do something. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array in a linked library will have the size it had at the point of linking. Changing the source without linking it again won't magically change the size in the lib.

Generally one provides a .h file and one or several .c file(s). The .c file(s) becomes the lib and the .h file contains all info required. It doesn't make sense to place an array in one .c file and declare its size in another .c file.